# how to increase no activity wait time in travis CI?

Tags: bash, travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

my test written for bash (which passes on my machine, test runs about 20-30 min) and I need to increase timeout for travis CI so that I can have successful build 
i have tried changing timeout by adding travis_wait 30 but i am getting error

```
sudo: required

arch:
  repos:
    - archlinuxfr=http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch
  packages:
    # pacman packages
    - yaourt
    - archiso
  script:
    - ./build-repo
    - travis_wait 30 sudo ./build.sh -v
```

the error i am getting

```
script:
  - "curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xeon-zolt/arch-travis/master/arch-travis.sh | bash"
travis_wait 30 sudo ./build.sh -v
/bin/bash: travis_wait: command not found
```

how to fix it please teach me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
script:
- "travis_wait 30 sleep 1800 &"
- curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xeon-zolt/arch-travis/master/arch-travis.sh | bash
```

inside arch chroot the travis_wait function do not work and if trying to export it it also gives error the best way is to use the command on the chroot part inside which everything takes place