# How to solve build timeout when using travis

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I'm setting up travis to push images to docker hub after running a test script

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker
before_install:
  - docker build -t oskygh/react-test -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client
script:
  - docker run oskygh/react-test npm test -- --coverage
after_success:
  - docker build -t osbee/client ./client
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin
  - docker push osbee/client
```

dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

Comment: The error I get is  build times out because no output was received

Comment: It would help to see your `Dockerfile.dev`, since that's what is timing out in Travis.

Comment: @wmorrell added the Dockerfile.dev

Comment: Ok, and your `package.json`. How long does it take to build this image locally? Since the only thing the image build is doing is `npm install`, the problem is likely something there.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received) you could use the `travis_wait` function. Adding it before the command, which failed. You could also read this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918874/how-to-increase-no-activity-wait-time-in-travis-ci), which added it in another way.

Comment: @OsborneSaka The last suggestion I have then, would be to move
`docker run oskygh/react-test npm test -- --coverage` to the before_install section and run your tests without docker under scripts. Good luck.